# Hiding component designators in rooms in Altium

Tags: altium

I have a multi-channel design that automatically generates rooms from my sheet symbols.
Designators for components in rooms tend to clutter up the silkscreen. Considering that all my rooms in my multi-channel design look exactly the same, I tend to manually hide the designators from all channels but the first, which is enough for identification.

Is there a way to "automate" this, by eg. setting designator visibility for specific rooms or for specific sheet symbols?

Comment: To prevent long designators in multi-channel designs, I usually change the settings for the Designator Format to something like $Component_$ChannelIndex or $Component$ChannelAlpha. That way designators end up as U1_1, U1_2, etc or U1A, U1B, etc. in the silkscreen. (This setting can be accessed under Project->Project Options under the Mulit-Channel tab.) I suppose you could just change this to $Component and they would all be the same and as short as possible. You could also hide the silk layer from the View Configuration during layout if its just the visual clutter that is the issue.

Comment: You could also change your preferences so that all designators are not visible by default (Preferences->PCB Editor->Defaults, under Primitives select Designator and then click the eyeball next to Value field to make invisibile). You would then need to make the designators visible again where you want them.

Comment: The problem with using the same designator in all channels is that component classes match components by designator, so if they are named the same it is as if all rooms/channels own the components from all the rooms/channels from the same signal class. Which means if you move the room, it moves components from all other rooms with it because they are named the same.

Comment: I see your point about the having the same designator, seems like a bad idea. Last thought is that you can fairly easily create a query to run in the PCB Filter to select all the designators you want to hide.  Something like IsDesignator and not WithinRoom('room1') -> select matching.

Comment: @gcr this is what I'm using at the moment. I was hoping for a "checkbox" solution because it looks to me that this is a common problem (repeating long designators creating a mess on the PCB).